# Using Group By and Roll Up for Specific Strings in SQL and Chartio

Tags: sql

I'm applying a filter in Chartio and it allows you to use SQL to create the filters query. Right now it's grouping each email provider separately. What I'd like it to do is have Gmail and AOL as separate but to rollup AcmeCo and RandCo into an "Other". What is the best way to do this?

My current default query to create the filter labels.

```
SELECT `Email Stats`.`provider` AS `Provider`
FROM `EmailStats` AS `Email Stats`
GROUP BY `Email Stats`.`provider`
```

Here is an example of my EmailStats table:

```
+------------+--------+----------------+  
| Date       | Clicks | Provider       |
+------------+--------+----------------+  
| 2015-12-13 |   10   |  Gmail         |
| 2015-12-13 |   2    |  AOL           |
| 2015-12-13 |   7    |  AcmeCo        |
| 2015-12-13 |   10   |  RandCo        |
| 2015-12-14 |   5    |  Gmail         |
| 2015-12-14 |   8    |  AOL           |
| 2015-12-14 |   12   |  AcmeCo        |
| 2015-12-14 |   18   |  RandCo        |
+------------+--------+----------------+
```

I'm new to SQL so I don't know what else would be helpful to finding an answer for this. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Found that I may need to use CASE query

    SELECT CASE m.campaign_id
               WHEN 'FB' THEN 'Facebook'
               ELSE m.campaign_id
           END AS "Campaign Id"
    FROM "public"."marketing" AS m
    GROUP BY "Campaign Id";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT `Email Stats`.`provider`
FROM `EmailStats` AS `Email Stats`
GROUP BY `Email Stats`.`provider`
CASE `Email Stats`.`provider`
 WHEN 'Gmail' THEN 'Gmail' 
 WHEN 'AOL' THEN 'AOL' 
 ELSE 'Other' 
END as `Provider`
```